# Tabs having fragments with listview are showing Blank screen

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity

On Opening the below Activity it is always showing a blankScreen. Please help I am new to android,
I am populating my list from database and performing some operations on that data and showing it in a listview. When I am populating this data in listview as a separate activity it is working fine, but when I am doing same with fragments it is showing Blank Screen.

**My Tab Activity Class**

```
package com.example.myexpensemanager;

import com.example.myexpensemanager.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class TabActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "All", "Daily", "Weekly","Monthly" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

**My Adapter Class**

```
package com.example.myexpensemanager.adapter;

import com.example.myexpensemanager.AllExpense;
import com.example.myexpensemanager.DailyExpense;
import com.example.myexpensemanager.MonthlyExpense;
import com.example.myexpensemanager.WeeklyExpense;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         switch (arg0) {
            case 0:

                return  new AllExpense();
            case 1:

                return new DailyExpense();
            case 2:
                // Movies fragment activity
                return new WeeklyExpense();
            case 3:
                // Movies fragment activity
                return new MonthlyExpense();
            }

            return null;
        }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**My One of the Fragment Class.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import cal_helper.Calendar_Helper;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class WeeklyExpense extends Fragment {
    ListView lv;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_history, container, false);
lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.history_list);

        populatedata();
        return rootView;
    }

private void populatedata() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



//      setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
//      populatedata();
        Log.d("POint: ", "0");


        //tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView123);
        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        Log.d("POint: ", "05");
        expensedb db = new expensedb(context);
        Log.d("POint: ", "04");
        Cursor cursor = db.getAllExpenses();
        Log.d("POint: ", "01");
        List<Expense> expenseList = new ArrayList<Expense>();
        Log.d("POint: ", "02");
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                   Expense expense = new Expense();
                expense.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                expense.setDateid(cursor.getString(1));
                expense.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
                expense.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                expense.setDate(cursor.getString(4));
                expense.setDateStamp(cursor.getString(5));
                expense.setCat_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)));
                // Adding contact to list
                expenseList.add(expense);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        Log.d("POint: ", "1");
ListMultimap<Integer, Expense> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
Map<Integer, Date> myMap = new TreeMap<Integer,Date>();
Calendar_Helper cal = new Calendar_Helper();
for (Expense x : expenseList) {
    Date date=cal.strtodate(x.getDate());
    int key =cal.weekOfYear(date) + cal.year(date)*100;
    myMultimap.put(key,x);
    myMap.put(key,date);
}
Log.d("POint: ", "2");
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
NavigableMap<Integer, Date> myMap1=((TreeMap<Integer, Date>) myMap).descendingMap();
for(Integer key : myMap1.keySet()){
    List<Expense> list = new ArrayList<Expense>();
    list = myMultimap.get(key);
    int amount = cal_amount(list);
    int week = cal.weekOfYear(myMap.get(key));
    int year = cal.year(myMap.get(key));
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("startdate", cal.startDate(week, year));
    map.put("enddate",cal.endDate(week, year));
    map.put("amount", Integer.toString(amount));
    mylist.add(map);
}
Log.d("POint: ", "4");

//now i have the all key values
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, mylist, R.layout.activity_week,
        new String[] {"startdate", "enddate", "amount"}, new int[] {R.id.tv_week, R.id.tv_week2, R.id.tv_Wamount});
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



private int cal_amount(List<Expense> list) {
    int amount=0;
    for(Expense x: list)
    {
        amount += x.getAmount();
    }
    return amount;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Count should be 4.

```
public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 4;
    }
```